# Normal PDF's integral not equal to one using MATLAB's normpdf

Tags: matlab, normal-distribution

The following methods are supposed to compute a PDF:

```
bins = [20 23 31.5 57 62.5 89 130];  % classes of values of my random variable

mean = 23;   
std  = mean/2;
values = mean + std*randn(1000,1);  % the actual values of the RV

% method 1

[num, bins] = hist(values, bins);  % histogram on the previously defined bins
pdf2 = num/trapz(bins, num);
trapz(bins, pdf2)  % checking the integral under the curve, which is indeed 1
ans =
 1

% method 2
pdf1 = normpdf(bins, mean, std); % the Matlab command for creating o normal PDF
trapz(bins, pdf1)  % this is NOT equal to 1
ans =
0.7069
```

However if I consider the bins something like

```
bins = [0:46];
```

the results are

```
ans =
 1
ans =
0.9544
```

so I still have not the value 1 for the integral in the case of `normpdf`.

Why does the `normpdf` not give the integral equal to 1 for the PDFs? Is there something I'm missing in the codes above?

Comment: Reminds me of students complaining that if they use their hand calculator  to divide  `1` by `3` and then multiply the result by `3` they get `0.999999999` and think the calculator's broken.

Comment: The OP does not complain it is broken, he merely observes something. And if your calculator shows that, you'd be wondering the first time too until someone tells you *why* that is happening. I think this question therefore valid, since he states an observation which does not hold conform the theory.

Comment: Indeed, I should have mention that my Matlab is not broken.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you are missing a lot of values from your PDF, if you take `bins = [0:46]`, you have the following curve:

[image]

Which means you are missing all the part `x < 0` and `x > 46`, so the integral you are computing is not from `-oo` to `+oo` as you expect but from `0` to `46`, obvisouly you won't get the correct answer.

Note that you have `mean = 23` and `std = 11.5`, thus if you have `bins = 0:46` you have a band around the mean with a width of one `std` on each side, so according to the [68–95–99.7 rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule), 95% of the values lie in this band, which is consistent with the 0.9544 you get.

If you take `bins = -11.5:57.5`, you now have three standard deviations on each side, and you will get `99.7%` of the values in this band (MATLAB gives me `0.9973`, the filled area are the ones you did not have with `bins = 0:46`):

[image]

Note that if you want to reach `1.000` with an error better than 10<sup>-3</sup>, you need about 3.4 standard deviations<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule)</sup>:

```
>> bins = (mean - 3.4 * std):(mean + 3.4 * std) ;
>> pdf  = normpdf(bins, mean, std) ;
>> trapz(bins, pdf)
0.9993
```

---

Note that with `bins = [20 23 31.5 57 62.5 89 130];`, you have both a problem of precision and a problem of missing values (your curve is the blue one, the red one was generated using `bins = 20:130`):

[image]

Obvisouly, if you compute the area under the blue curve, you won't get the value of the area under the red one, and you won't certainly get a value close to the integral of the red curve between `-oo` and `+oo`.

Comment: Thanks @Holt, that is true, I didn't think of that.